# Prove that the limit equals $1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, limits

Does $\lim_{n \to \infty}\operatorname{length}\{ x^n(1-x)^n:x\in[0,1],n\in \Bbb R^+\}=1?$ I'd like to prove this result analytically, but I'm not sure how.

The formula for arc length that I've been using is $s=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+(dy/dx)^2}dx.$

Comment: are you sure the limit isn't $0$?

Comment: Ach.... nevermind....  I misunderstood what you meant by "length"  I thought you meant the length strictly as a subset of $\mathbb R$ and  not $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Not to nitpick but shouldn't it be $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty; n\in \mathbb R^+}\text{length} \{(x,y): y= x^n(1-x)^n,x\in[0,1],\}$?

Comment: @fleablood yes thanks! I tried another example using your more precise notation: $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty; n\in \mathbb R^+}\text{surface area} \{(x,y): y= x^n(1-x)^n,x\in[0,1],\}=\pi.$

Comment: revolved around the line $x=1/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write down $dy/dx$ and use the inequality $x(1-x) \leq \frac 1 4$. You will see that $s \leq \sqrt {1+\frac {n^{2}} {4^{n-1}}}$. From this it is clear that $s \to 1$ ( $s \geq 1$ is obvious). [$x(1-x)$ attains its maximum at $x=\frac 1 2$].